# How to parse non seperated date format?

Tags: c#, datetime

How to parse non saperated dates like `20210729` format.

Normally c# parses if formatted `2021-07-29`

```
DateTime.Parse(`2021-07-29`)
```

But not seperated dates is not seperated.

Comment: `"20210729".Substring(0,4)` will give you the year, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this for custom formats:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(datestring, "yyyyMMdd", ci, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)
```

Comment: Yep, that works.